# Как правильно авторизировать пользователя по ip JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, авторизация

Делаю сайт типа dropmefiles (онлайн хранилище файлов), на котором нужно как-то идентифицировать пользователей. Это можно делать с помощью обычной регистрации с логином и паролем, но это не очень быстрый способ для пользователя (на это ему нужно будет тратить время). Поэтому хочу использовать авторизацию по ip адресу клиента с помощью geoPlugin. То есть клиент открывает сайт, geoPlugin получает ip и отправляет его бекэнду, а бекэнд уже определяет, что возвращать в зависимости от того зарегистрирован ли данный ip или нет.

Вопрос в том, насколько это безопасно для клиента - может ли злоумышленник подставить в свой запрос чужой ip, чтобы получить доступ к чужим файлам, и если да, то как это можно от этого защититься?

Comment: На IP-адрес полагаться ни в коем случае нельзя, потому что один и тот же адрес может быть у тысяч разных пользователей

Comment: @andreymal geoPlugin возвращает json с ip и другими разными данными типа широты, долготы, города и т.д. Если я из них что-то вроде хеша буду делать, будет лучше?

Comment: У таких данных никудышная точность и они тоже будут совпадать у разных пользователей

Comment: Ну и все упомянутые вами характеристики пользователя могут и скорее всего будут меняться со временем, даже в течение одного дня

Comment: @andreymal окей, спасибо, а есть какой-либо еще способ автоматической авторизации без ввода логина и пароля пользователем

Comment: Ну, обычные куки?

Comment: (да и в общем-то с регистрацией ведь тоже используются те же самые куки, но никто не запрещает использовать куки и без регистрации)

Comment: @andreymal то есть генерировать какой-то ключ, вставлять его в куки и отправлять бекэнду запрос с куками?

Answer (score 1):

Плохая идея... Вы пытаетесь изобрести велосипед. Примите как факт, что так никто не делает.

Люди могут заходить на сайт из дома или офиса, а в офисе у меня например более 200 человек сидит под одним внешним ip. А если кто-то захочет зайти с чужого компьютера?

Лучше сделайте простейшую форму регистрации, чтобы пользователю достаточно было ввести например только номер телефона.

Или автризацию гугл, эпл, гит, вк и пр.

А после того как посетитель оставил свои данные сохраняйте куки, чтобы при повторном посещении сайта подтягивать нужные данные из бекэнда.